# Changing categorized style color simultaneously in QGIS?

Tags: polygon, symbology, style, qgis-2.12, color-ramp

I work with this polygon:

[image]

[image]

and i need that all features will be with border line only without fil colors. I seek for a way to do it simultaneously to all the categorized features, and not treat every feature seperatly.

So the result will be only border lines with a ramp color like in features 12 and 25 (i changed them manually for the example).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on "Change" Symbol at the top header

[image]

Go to Simple Fill -> under Fill style change to No Brush

[image]

All the filled polygons will be changed to outline only.

[image]

If you are using Ruled-based, then select all symbols by holding the Shift button on your keyboard, then right-cleck and go to change color, and set opacity to 0%.

[image]

Comment: @newGIS asked for "border lines with a ramp color". This is different from your suggested solution. I am also looking for a solution to the same use case, but have not found anything suitable yet.

Answer (score 2):

the option you are probably looking for can be found in the Symbol Selector were you can change the symbol layer type of your polygon layer to Outline. You can then change the appearance of your polygon outlines according to a category (Screenshot from QGIS 3.8).
 [image: Screenshot of QGIS 3.8]

Comment: This one took me a good hour. Thank you so much!